# Typescript import interface with same name as class

Tags: typescript, class, import, interface

Below works:

```
interface Foo {
  num: number;
}

class Foo {
}
```

Below doesn't work, error

> Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Foo'

```
import { Foo } from "./someModule";
class Foo {
}
```

Is this intended behaviour? If I am able to create an interface and class with the same name in one module, why not be able to import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is different in the two cases. In the first case you don't end up with an interface and a class, you end up with a single class that is a merger of the two. The behavior is described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). This behavior can't happen across modules however.

If you want to augment an existing module the behavior you want is called module augmentation and is also described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Comment: In case of IFoo & Foo from the example above, what would module augmentation look like? Could you add it to the answer?